# jqGrid place sort arrow icon on the left

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

How i can place sort arrow icon on the left in filter headers?

[image: example]

I see the problem as the implementation because arrows container (s-ico) is inside the container header (ui-jqgrid-sortable) ...

```
<div id="jqgh_mylist_pDate" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
     Date
     <span class="s-ico">
          <span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span>
          <span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span>
      </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long time i try to find answer to my question and made my own solution

Difference between sortable and not sortable columns only in style in first **span** tag - **display:none**

In begin i tried to detect sortable columns by use **:hidden** selector, but all columns have only blank **span**s and this selector return true for both type of columns

```
<!-- sortable -->
<div id="jqgh_manager" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
    Manager
    <span class="s-ico">
        <span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span>
        <span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span>
    </span>
</div>

<!-- not sortable -->
<div id="jqgh_operator" class="ui-jqgrid-sortable">
    Operator
    <span class="s-ico" style="display:none">
        <span sort="asc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-asc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n ui-sort-ltr"></span>
        <span sort="desc" class="ui-grid-ico-sort ui-icon-desc ui-state-disabled ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-sort-ltr"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

so, we can check rule of style for span tag

```
// Moving the arrows of sorting to the left side
jQuery.jgrid.extend({
    moveSortArrows: function (){
        // Moving only sorted cols
        // We must check style rule, because we can not use :hidden selector since this selector 
        // return true if width and height equal 0
        // For more information see official documentations - http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/
        $('.ui-jqgrid-sortable:has(span.s-ico:not([style*="display:none"]))').each(
            function() {
                // Add left padding for moving arrows
                $(this).css('padding-left', '16px');
                // Moving arrows
                $(this).find('span.s-ico').css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "left": 0
                });
            }
        );
    }
});
```

[image]